# What´s the difference between AtomicReference<Integer> vs. AtomicInteger?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, atomicreference

I don´t get the difference between these two:

```
AtomicReference<Integer> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(1);
```

vs.

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
```

Can someone generally say when to use AtomicReference?
Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A very important difference is that the methods `compareAndSet` and `weakCompareAndSet` have different semantics for `AtomicReference<Integer>` than they do for `AtomicInteger`. This is because with `AtomicReference<Integer>`, those methods use `==` for comparing and two `Integer` objects can be equal without being `==`. With `AtomicInteger`, the comparison is of the integer value equality, not reference identity.

As others have pointed out, `AtomicInteger` has additional features not available with `AtomicReference<Integer>`. Also, `AtomicInteger` extends `Number`, so it inherits all the `Number` methods (`doubleValue()`, etc.) and can be used whenever a `Number` is expected.

Comment: Its worth pointing out also that auto-boxed Integer objects in the range -127 to 128 are interned and that their == will return true while Integers outside this range will not. Integers created with `new Integer(3)` will obviously not have the same identity though. This can cause all sorts of surprising behaviours.

Comment: @JedWesley-Smith - Excellent point. According to the API,  values outside that range _might_ also be cached. So to make matters worse the "surprising behaviours" may be different on different Java platforms.

Comment: Right, it is an undocumented hack that should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 8):

Not much difference if you are using just `set(...)` and `get()` but the `AtomicInteger` has some other methods such as `incrementAndGet()` which only work for integers.

The `AtomicReference` wraps a `volatile Object` while `AtomicInteger` wraps a `volatile int` so it can do integer specific methods including increment, decrement, and add methods.  `AtomicInteger` also extends `Number` which means it supports `doubleValue()`, `longValue()`,  etc. methods.

Answer (score 6):

`AtomicReference` is a generic class that can refer to arbitrary types.
If you want to use an instance of your own class atomically, you need `AtomicReference<V>`.

`AtomicInteger` is a specialized version that contains integers.  It is more efficient (no unnecessary boxing), and has useful methods like `incrementAndGet()`.

Comment: Also, two `Integer` objects can be equal without being identical.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, `AtomicReference<Integer>` uses == to compare objects. Therefore,`compareAndSet(expect, update)` will update your initial reference only if `expect` equals to the object stored in your your atomic reference using ==.

It can lead to some tricky bugs if you use `AtomicReference` for numeric types, i.e. `Integer` or `Long`. Please note that static constructors of those classes (for example, `Integer.valueOf(int value)`) return internally cached objects for small values. In other words, two different calls to `Integer.valueOf(5)` returns the same instance of `Integer`. It is safe, as the classes are immutable. In the result, if you use `AtomicReference<Integer>` whereas you should really be using `AtomicInteger`, it may work fine for these small numbers, because == may actually compare the same objects. It gets worse only when you begin to handle with higher values at some point.

Summing up, using `AtomicInteger` is much safer for numeric operations :)

Comment: See comment on Ted Hopp's answer, the interning of the Integer objects only happens for a restricted set, not for all. Relying on the interning to make == work is considered harmful as it is undocumented and may change.

Comment: Well, that is what I meant by "small values". I did not want to specify the range, as it may be a subject to change. My conclusion was exactly what you are saying: you should never rely on == to work for numeric objects.